# how to define your own two different .phtml frontend pages in custom layout file in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a module in which i have created a custom template file which i have successfully called now. And I want to create another template file in same folder but how do I define it in layout xml file ?

Comment: your custom module has it's layout file?

Comment: yes am working on my own layout

Comment: you can define it same as you did for your previous template file or you are having any other requirement? please elaborate

Comment: <repair_index_index>
  <reference name="root">
   <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
  </reference>
  <reference name="content">
   <block type="repair/repair" template="repair/content.phtml"/>
  </reference>
 </repair_index_index>

I had defined my 1st template file as this but on  defining the 2nd one i that dosen't call the 1st one too

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your own block class then you can do like this,

```
<repair_index_index> 
<reference name="root"> 
<action method="setTemplate"> <template>page/1column.phtml</template>                           
</action> 
   </reference> 
    <reference name="content"> 
   <block type="repair/repair" name="mytemplate" template="repair/content.phtml"/>
   <block type="repair/repair" name="mynewtemplate" template="repair/newcontent.phtml"/>
   </reference>
```

Here newcontent.html is your new template file.
Or you can use core/template as a block type, if you haven't registered your module.

Comment: I had tried in this way also but it didn't work.. and my module is registered

Comment: check the file name and path once again. What happened when you tried this.?

Comment: Both template files didn't work when i did call both blocks in same reference

Comment: try calling the new template file from default content and see if it works

Comment: i already tried that way too but unfortunately it also didn't work